# How do I change the style of an "<input>" element dynamically using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm working on an application that has 2 tables on the left side and a row on the right side, on the table when the user selects any number, the values are dynamically added on the rows on the right side.

This works as expected but I'm trying to add CSS where if the user hovers on the input on the row (on the right side) it changes to green and the corresponding value/td on the table background color immediately changes to green.

Here is my attempt:

```js
// window.onload = function () { alert("Js working!") };
let currentInput = 1;
let bonusInput = 1;

$("#table1").on('click', function(event) {
  let num = event.target.textContent;
  $("#inp" + currentInput++).attr("value", num);
});

// bonus input:
$("#table2").on('click', function(event) {
  let bon = event.target.textContent;
  $("#bonus" + bonusInput++).attr("value", bon);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Table on the left -->
<div style="width: 140px; float: left;">
  <table id="table1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- Rows on the right-->

<!--2nd table-->
<div style="width: 140px; float: left; margin-left: 12px;">
  <table id="table2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- Rows on the right-->

<!-- Input values to populate dynamically-->
<div style="width: 600px; float: right;">
  <div>
    <input type="text" size="4" id="inp1" value="">
    <input type="text" size="4" id="inp2" value="">
    <input type="text" size="4" id="inp3" value="">
    <input type="text" size="4" id="inp4" value="">
    <input type="text" size="4" id="inp5" value=""> +
    <input style="margin-left: 20px;" type="text" size="4" id="bonus1" value="">
  </div>

  <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
    <input type="text" size="4" id="inp7" value="">
    <input type="text" size="4" id="inp8" value="">
    <input type="text" size="4" id="inp9" value="">
    <input type="text" size="4" id="inp10" value="">
    <input type="text" size="4" id="inp11" value=""> +
    <input style="margin-left: 20px;" type="text" size="4" id="bonus2" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the screenshot of the result:

[image: image screenshot]

Comment: Can you post your code on fiddle?

Comment: That is not possible using CSS alone, with such an HTML structure. You will have to use JavaScript for this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JavaScript instead:

```js
// window.onload = function () { alert("Js working!") };

let currentInput = 1;
let bonusInput = 1;

$("#table1").on('click', function(event) {
  let num = event.target.textContent;
  $("#inp" + currentInput++).attr("value", num);
});

//Bonus input
$("#table2").on('click', function(event) {
  let bon = event.target.textContent;
  $("#bonus" + bonusInput++).attr("value", bon);
});
$('#result input').hover(function() {
  var key = parseInt(this.id.replace(/(inp|bonus)/gm, ''), 10);
  var dir = this.id.indexOf('bonus') >= 0 ? '1' : '2';
  var row = (key > 6 || this.id == 'bonus2') ? 1 : 0;
  var col = key % 6;
  $('td').attr('style', '');
  $('input').attr('style', '');
  var table = '1';
  if (dir == 1) table = '2';
  var compare_key = this.value;
  $('#table' + table + ' td').each(function() {
    if (this.innerText.trim() == compare_key) {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'green').css('color', 'white');
    }
  });
  $(this).css('background-color', 'green').css('color', 'white');
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 15px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

#table1 td {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Draggable Bootstrap nav-tabs with jQuery UI</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Draggable Bootstrap nav-tabs with jQuery UI">
  <!-- include bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Table on the left -->
  <div style="width: 140px; float: left;">
    <table id="table1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- Rows on the right-->

  <!--2nd table-->
  <div style="width: 140px; float: left; margin-left: 12px;">
    <table id="table2">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- Rows on the right-->

  <!-- Input values to populate dynamically-->
  <div id="result" style="width: 600px; float: right;">
    <div>
      <input type="text" size="4" id="inp1" value="">
      <input type="text" size="4" id="inp2" value="">
      <input type="text" size="4" id="inp3" value="">
      <input type="text" size="4" id="inp4" value="">
      <input type="text" size="4" id="inp5" value=""> +
      <input style="margin-left: 20px;" type="text" size="4" id="bonus1" value="">
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
      <input type="text" size="4" id="inp7" value="">
      <input type="text" size="4" id="inp8" value="">
      <input type="text" size="4" id="inp9" value="">
      <input type="text" size="4" id="inp10" value="">
      <input type="text" size="4" id="inp11" value=""> +
      <input style="margin-left: 20px;" type="text" size="4" id="bonus2" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- include jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

  <!-- include jQuery UI -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <!-- include bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot it works fine,, Am trying to customize your code further when the user hovers on a single row (on the right side),, all the td fields on the table (on the left side) that match with that row are highlighted ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is more efficient ways to do this. I've just played around with classes. You can try the code snippet.

```js
// window.onload = function () { alert("Js working!") };
let currentInput = 1;
let bonusInput = 1;

$("#table1").on('click', function(event) {
  let num = event.target.textContent;
  $("#inp" + currentInput++).attr("value", num);
});

//Bonus input
$("#table2").on('click', function(event) {
  let bon = event.target.textContent;
  $("#bonus" + bonusInput++).attr("value", bon);
});

$(".leftCell").mouseover(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (val != "") {
    var cell = $('#table1').find('.' + val)
    cell.css("background-color", "green")
  }
});

$(".leftCell").mouseout(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (val != "") {
    var cell = $('#table1').find('.' + val)
    cell.css("background-color", "white")
  }
});

$(".rightCell").mouseover(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (val != "") {
    var cell = $('#table2').find('.' + val)
    cell.css("background-color", "green")
  }
});

$(".rightCell").mouseout(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (val != "") {
    var cell = $('#table2').find('.' + val)
    cell.css("background-color", "white")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 140px; float: left;">
  <table id="table1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="1">1</td>
        <td class="2">2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="3">3</td>
        <td class="4">4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="5">5</td>
        <td class="6">6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="7">7</td>
        <td class="8">8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="9">9</td>
        <td class="10">10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- Rows on the right-->

<!--2nd table-->
<div style="width: 140px; float: left; margin-left: 12px;">
  <table id="table2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="1">1</td>
        <td class="2">2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="3">3</td>
        <td class="4">4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="5">5</td>
        <td class="6">6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="7">7</td>
        <td class="8">8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="9">9</td>
        <td class="10">10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- Rows on the right-->

<!-- Input values to populate dynamically-->
<div style="width: 600px; float: right;">
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="leftCell" size="4" id="inp1" value="">
    <input type="text" class="leftCell" size="4" id="inp2" value="">
    <input type="text" class="leftCell" size="4" id="inp3" value="">
    <input type="text" class="leftCell" size="4" id="inp4" value="">
    <input type="text" class="leftCell" size="4" id="inp5" value=""> +
    <input style="margin-left: 20px;" type="text" size="4" id="bonus1" class="rightCell" value="">
  </div>

  <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
    <input type="text" class="leftCell" size="4" id="inp7" value="">
    <input type="text" class="leftCell" size="4" id="inp8" value="">
    <input type="text" class="leftCell" size="4" id="inp9" value="">
    <input type="text" class="leftCell" size="4" id="inp10" value="">
    <input type="text" class="leftCell" size="4" id="inp11" value=""> +
    <input style="margin-left: 20px;" type="text" size="4" id="bonus2" class="rightCell" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```